# Adding movie overview TextView in xml inside a Scrollbar

Tags: android, xml, scrollbar, view

I have the following xml. Basically I want to display the movie overview below the Layout whose id is equals to *layoutOne*.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutOne"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/primary"
                    >


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/movie_image"
                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                        android:layout_height="240dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        />

                       <RelativeLayout
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:padding="16dp"
                           android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                           <TextView
                               android:id="@+id/movie_title"
                               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:textSize="16sp"

                               />

                           <TextView
                               android:layout_below="@+id/movie_title"
                               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                               android:id="@+id/movie_rating"
                               android:text="9/10"
                               android:textSize="24sp"
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:paddingTop="20dp"
                               />
                           <LinearLayout
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_below="@+id/movie_rating"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:orientation="horizontal">
                               <ImageView
                                   android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar"/>
                               <TextView
                                   android:layout_below="@+id/movie_rating"
                                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                   android:id="@+id/movie_date"
                                   android:text="2017-10-9"
                                   android:textSize="16sp"

                                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:paddingTop="20dp"
                                   />

                           </LinearLayout>


                       </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title_overview"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Great movie" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>
```

Here is what I get.

[image: movie details]

I want the sample text *Great movie* to be below that light pink layout. The tricky part here is that Scrollbar view allow only one child view. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Constraint of the `RelativeLayout` should fit the whole page. If you want to use `ScrollView` you should add the `RelativeLayout` to the `ScrollView` too.

Hence it would be like this :

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutOne"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/primary"
                    >
```

Later you can use the following to adjust the image:

```
    <LinearLayout
  android:layout_marginBottom="439dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>
```